# Summation Formula as an answer:

Tags: multivariable-calculus, summation

I am given the following multi-variable function:
$$f(x_1,x_2,x_3,...,x_n)=\sum_\limits{k=1}^nkx_k$$

Find $f(1,1,1,...,1)$

Why is the answer $\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}$?

Is it because $x_n=1$ thus leaving $\sum_\limits{k=1}^nk\therefore\text{the answer is } \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$

Comment: yes you have the correct answer

Comment: Yes, and $\sum_{k=1}^{n}k=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ because $2\sum_{k=1}^{n}k=(1+2+...+n)+(n+(n-1)+...+1)=(1+n)+(2+(n-1))+(3+(n-2))...+(n+1)=n(n+1)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just expand:

$\begin{align*}
   f(x_1, \dotsc, x_n)
     &= \sum_{1 \le k \le n} k x_k \\
   f(1, \dotsc, 1)
     &= \sum_{1 \le k \le n} k \\
     &= \frac{n (n + 1)}{2}
\end{align*}$

The last by the known formula for the sum of an arithmetic series.